# Javascript - get value of variable without declaring a second one

Tags: javascript, variables

```js
var i = 5;
test();

function test() {
  let i = 3;
  alert(i);
}
```

The above example alerts the value of the second variable that is `3`. How can I code it to alert the value of the first while keeping the two with the same name? Thanks

Comment: How about `alert(5)`?

Comment: Yur search term for Google might be: the scope of a variable.

Comment: It might be that you have an idea that you're not expressing clearly.  Might be that you want to always alert the contents of some global, or perhaps something else.  Please consider rewording your question.  Currently you're going to get really trivial answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it's global namespace, i.e. the global `window` variable.

```js
var i = 5;
test();

function test() {
  let i = 3;
  alert(window.i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, also `this.i` seems to work the same in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Use outside scope

```js
var i = 5;
test();

function test() {
  // let i = 3;
  alert(i);
}
```

or make it a function parameter

```js
// var i = 5;
test(5);

function test(i) {
  // let i = 3;
  alert(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is this:

```js
var i = 5;
test(i);

function test(x) {
  alert(x);
}
```